# user.joinedAt displays current time

Tags: discord.js

The code is [here](https://pastebin.com/VR7rGsKk). In line 41, `user.joinedAt` displays the current date and time instead of the user's joined-in date. What is the issue there? I have done research online but those either display the current time or errors in my console. I heard that I would have to use `member.joinedAt`, but then I would have to define "member". "user" is already defined as you can conclude in the code.

Comment: Can we see your code

Comment: It's in the link. https://pastebin.com/VR7rGsKk

Comment: In the future, edit the code as text into your description

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) does **not** have a `joinedAt` property. Therefore, the date being used is: `moment.utc(undefined)`, which defaults to the latest date.

Instead, you need to use a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember). In your code, you can do this by using [`message.mentions.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members):

```js
let member = message.mentions.members.first();
```

However, you are also using `user.createdAt`, which a `GuildMember` does not have. You can access the `createdAt` property through the [`GuildMember.user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) property, which contains the `createdAt` property:

```js
let user = member.user;
```

Then you can use the correct values like so:

```js
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle(`Userinfo`) 
  .setColor(`BLUE`)
  .setThumbnail(user.avatarURL({ size: 2048, dynamic: true }))
  .addFields (
    {name: `Username + tag`, value: `${user.tag}`, inline: true},
    {name: `Server join date`, value: `${moment.utc(member.joinedAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")} UTC`, inline: true },
    {name: `User creation date`, value: `${moment.utc(user.createdAt).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a")} UTC`, inline: true}
  );
```